# Singleton classes - ruby vs java

Tags: java, ruby, singleton

To the best of my knowledge, these are how the singleton classes are used in Java and Ruby

- In Java, singleton classes are classes for which only one instance can exist.
- In Ruby, singleton classes are classes which act as buffer between an object and its original class, so as to hold the custom methods (singleton methods) for that particular object (which by extension means that the singleton classes will have only one object at the maximum)

To sum up, singleton classes in ruby are the same as those in java except for the facility to hold custom methods. Have I understood it right or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Do you expect a yes/no answer?

Comment: You ask how they are used, and then conclude describing their facility?  So what are you asking?  This question is confusing.

Comment: @EelLee If I have covered all the necessary points, then a yes would do. If not I would like to know what I have missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are technically correct, but I think there's a big difference that you don't mention.

In Java, a singleton class is something that you **implement**. In other words, it's a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which is generally only used in specific cases (see the link for examples). The singleton pattern is also widely considered to be a bad idea, so singleton classes are best avoided in Java.

In Ruby, a singleton class is something **implicit** to every Object. It's always there, but is only utilized when the programmer wants to make class-level changes on a per-instance basis (like adding methods). It is similar to the Java case *only* in the sense that it can have only one instance. Singleton classes in Ruby are very handy and can be very powerful when used with metaprogramming.

Of course you can also implement the singleton pattern in Ruby, but when a Rubyist says "singleton class" they are always referring to the implicit ancestor of every Object.